# Javascript Learnstreet Email Interpreter Alternative Solution

Tags: javascript

So I was doing this assignment on Learnstreet and for those of you who want to read a little on the question here's the link:

http://www.learnstreet.com/cg/simple/project/email_interpret#check

Long story short - you're given a email string like "local@domain.com" and you're expected to return a 2 member array that would look like ["local","domain"]. So I wrote this and am wondering how this is not correct.

```
function extractLocalDomain(str)
    {
        var text = str.trim();    //eliminates leading and trailing spaces
        for(var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {

            if(text[i] == "@") {
                 var local = text.slice(0, i-1);  
                 var domain = text.slice(i+1)
                 return [local,domain];
             }
             i++
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are incrementing `i` twice:

```
function extractLocalDomain(str) {
    var text = str.trim();
    for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) { // <- increment here
        if (text[i] == "@") {
            var local = text.slice(0, i - 1);
            var domain = text.slice(i + 1)
            return [local, domain];
        }
        i++ // <- and here agin, remove this
    }
}
```

Instead of using a loop, you can also just use [`.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).